# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions'). | Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I'm making a command called role info in slash command!
And came the error called: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions').

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment");
moment.locale("pt-BR");
module.exports = {
  name: "role",
  description: "｢│ Utilidades｣ Obtenha informações de um cargo",
      options: [
        {
          name: 'info',
  description: "｢│ Utilidades｣ Obtenha informações de um cargo",
          type: "SUB_COMMAND",
    
  options: [
    {
      name: "role",
      type: "ROLE",
      description: "O cargo que você deseja obter as informações!",
      required: true,
      
        }]
    },
    ],
  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
        
    const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0]);
     const permissions = {
            "ADMINISTRATOR": "Administrador",
            "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG": "Ver Registro de Auditoria",
            "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS": "Exibir insights do servidor",
            "MANAGE_GUILD": "Gerenciar Servidor",
            "MANAGE_ROLES": "Gerenciar Cargos",
            "MANAGE_CHANNELS": "Gerenciar Canais",
            "KICK_MEMBERS": "Expulsar Membros",
            "BAN_MEMBERS": "Banir Membros",
            "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE": "Criar convite",
            "CHANGE_NICKNAME": "Mudar apelido",
            "MANAGE_NICKNAMES": "Gerenciar apelidos",
            "MANAGE_EMOJIS": "Gerenciar Emojis",
            "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS": "Gerenciar webhooks",
            "VIEW_CHANNEL": "Ler canais de texto e ver canais de voz",
            "SEND_MESSAGES": "Enviar mensagens",
            "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES": "Enviar mensagens TTS",
            "MANAGE_MESSAGES": "Gerenciar mensagens",
            "EMBED_LINKS": "Embed Links",
            "ATTACH_FILES": "Anexar arquivos",
            "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY": "Leia o histórico da mensagem",
            "MENTION_EVERYONE": "Mencione @everyone, @here e Todos os cargos",
            "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS": "Usar Emojis Externos",
            "ADD_REACTIONS": "Adicionar Reações",
            "CONNECT": "Conectar",
            "SPEAK": "Falar",
            "STREAM": "Video",
            "MUTE_MEMBERS": "Mutar Membros",
            "DEAFEN_MEMBERS": "Ensurdecer membros",
            "MOVE_MEMBERS": "Mover membros",
            "USE_VAD": "Usar atividade de voz",
            "PRIORITY_SPEAKER": "Orador prioritário"
        }

        const yesno = {
            true: '`Sim`',
            false: '`Não`'
        }


        const rolePermissions = role.permissions.toArray();
        const finalPermissions = [];
        for (const permission in permissions) {
            if (rolePermissions.includes(permission)) finalPermissions.push(`${client.emoji.success} ${permissions[permission]}`);
            else finalPermissions.push(`${client.emoji.fail} ${permissions[permission]}`);
        }

        const position = `\`${interaction.guild.roles.cache.size - role.position}°\``;
        
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        
        .setTitle(`${role.name}`)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.id} ID`, `\`${role.id}\``, true)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.trophy} Posição`, `${position}`, true)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.ping} Mencionável`, yesno[role.mentionable], true)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.bot} Cargo de bot`, yesno[role.managed], true)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.on} Visível`, yesno[role.hoist], true)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.rcolor} Cor`, `\`${role.hexColor.toUpperCase()}\``, true)
        .addField(`${client.emoji.calendar} Data de criação`, `${moment(role.createdAt).format('LLL')}(${moment(role.createdAt).startOf('day').fromNow()})`, true)
        .setColor(`${role.hexColor.toUpperCase()}`)
              
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
      .setLabel(`Permissões`)
    .setEmoji(`${client.emoji.perms}`)
             .setCustomId('perms')        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
);
     const m = await interaction.followUp({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] })
        const iFilter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

        const collector = m.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: iFilter, time: 10 * 60000 });

        collector.on('collect', async(i) => {
      
          switch (i.customId) { //começo da mensagem 
                case `perms`:
                    i.reply({
                        embeds: [
                            
                            new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`${client.emoji.perms} Permissões`)
                                .setDescription(`${finalPermissions.join('\n')}
`)
        .setColor(`${role.hexColor.toUpperCase()}`)
                        ],
ephemeral: true                    })
                 }
        }) //Final da mensagem 
    
    }                    
}
```

Since before, the command was working, but I changed it to the second bot and then it gave the error!
If anyone knows, tell me the error, I would be very grateful!
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefine
d (reading 'permissions')
at Object.run (/home/runner//Slash/Info/roleinfo.js:66:38)
at Client. (/home/runner//events/interactionCreate:24:13

InteractionCreate.js

```
const client = require("../index");

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    // Slash Command Handling
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: false }).catch(() => {});
        const cmd = client.slash.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!cmd)
            return interaction.followUp({ content: "An error has occured " });

        const args = [];

        for (let option of interaction.options.data) {
            if (option.type === "SUB_COMMAND") {
                if (option.name) args.push(option.name);
                option.options?.forEach((x) => {
                    if (x.value) args.push(x.value);
                });
            } else if (option.value) args.push(option.value);
        }
        interaction.member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);

        cmd.run(client, interaction, args);
    }

    // Context Menu Handling
    if (interaction.isContextMenu()) {
      //  await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
        const command = client.slash.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (command) command.run(client, interaction);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing in the args parameter in your function execution. You can remove args and use `<CommandInteraction>.options.getRole()` to get the role argument. Now keeping that in mind we can go ahead and define role as that.

```js
const role = interaction.options.getRole("role");
```